# What is making this page cut off early?

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I will include the entire php file for reference, since I'm having a very hard time figuring out at what point conflicts are happening. The problem is that the page stops displaying the rest of the forms following the dropdown menu. When the first section of php is commented out, everything works, so I suspect there is something wrong in there but I need help to figure it out.

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['update_post'])) {
    $postTitle = $_POST['title'];
    $postAuthor = $_POST['author'];
    $postCatId = $_POST['post_cat_id'];
    $postStatus = $_POST['status'];
    $postContent = $_POST['content'];
    $postImage = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $postImageTemp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $postTags = $_POST['tags'];
    $postDate = date('d-m-y');
    $postCommentCount = 4;

    move_uploaded_file($postImageTemp, "../images/$postImage");

    $queryupdate = $db->prepare("UPDATE posts (post_category_id, post_title, post_author, post_date,
                        post_content, post_image, post_tags, post_comment_count, post_status) VALUES
                        ($postCatId, '$postTitle', '$postAuthor', now(), '$postContent', '$postImage',
                        '$postTags', '$postCommentCount', '$postStatus')");

    if (!$queryupdate) {
        die("MySQL Fatal Exception: " . $db->error);
        exit;
    }
    else {
        $queryupdate->execute();
        echo "<strong class='text-success'>Post Successfully Created</strong>";
    }
}


?>

<?php
if(isset($_GET['post_id'])) {
    $getID = $_GET['post_id'];
    echo $getID;
    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_id = $getID");
    $query->bind_result($id,$catId,$title,$author,$date,$content,$image,$tags,$comments,$status);
    $query->execute();
}
?>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Post Title</label>
        <input value="<?php echo $title; ?>" type="text" class="form-control" name="title">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="post_category">Post Category</label>
        <br>
        <select name="" id="">
            <?php
            $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `categories`");
            if (!$stmt) {
                echo "Connection fail";
                exit;
            }
            $stmt->bind_result($catIDdrop, $catTitle);
            $stmt->execute();
            while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                echo "<option value =''>$catTitle</option>";
            }
            $stmt->close();
            ?>

        </select>

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="post_author">Post Author</label>
        <input value="<?php echo $author; ?>" type="text" class="form-control" name="author">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="post_status">Post Status</label>
        <input value="<?php echo $status; ?>" type="text" class="form-control" name="status">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="post_image">Post Image</label>
        <img alt="post img" src="../images/<?php echo $image; ?>">
        <input type="file" name="image">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="post_tags">Post Tags</label>
        <input value="<?php echo $tags; ?>" type="text" class="form-control" name="tags">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="post_content">Post Content</label>
        <textarea value="<?php echo $content; ?>" class="form-control" name="content" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
        </textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="update_post" value="Update">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: What error messages are you getting?

Comment: What is the structure of `categories` table?

Comment: @PeterFeatherstone No error messages are displayed on the page.

Comment: Do you have php errors turned on and to display? Have you tried putting ini_set('display_errors', 1); at the top of your file? Or have you checked your error logs?

Comment: @u_mulder categories contains to columns, a auto increment cat_id key and another column named cat_title.

Comment: Can you show the you commented out.  But i noticed you are using get method to get post values on line 2

Comment: What if you first `execute` and then `bind_result`?

Comment: @PeterFeatherstone I have received plenty of errors before this case. I am unsure of where I would check my error logs, however. I am using xammp and phpmyadmin if that helps.

Comment: It is even said in a manual: `Note that all columns must be bound after mysqli_stmt_execute() and prior to calling mysqli_stmt_fetch().`

Comment: @u_mulder Swapping the order of those methods does not appear to do anything.

Comment: @u_mulder I don't believe that is correct. I have bound results before execute elsewhere in this project and it has worked just fine.

Comment: You have two places with `bind_result`, sure that you changed correct one?

Comment: @u_mulder I tried changing both. No change in result.

Comment: If this is entire php file - where's `$db` defined?

Comment: @u_mulder This is an entire php file which is included as a part of a different file. On that "parent"(?) file the $db connection file is included before this file is, so I don't think there's a problem there.